# Bootstrap carousel responsive img

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I want to have the img in the carousel responsive. The height should be 100vh but the width needs to be as wide as it goes, depending on how big the img is. The overflowing part should be hidden. Now, when the screen gets smaller, the img is resized not to scale. Here's some screen shots

This is fine at full width, desktop version
[image: This is fine at full width, desktop version]

This is about the witdh of tablets, but there are white space at the bottom which i dont want.
[image]

This is the phone version, resized but not to scale. It should also takes up the whole window, but the overflowing width can be hidden.
[image]

This is what I have for css:

```css
.carousel,
.carousel-inner {
     height: 100vh;
}

.carousel img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="photos/JO2_2978.JPG" alt="xmas_orchestra">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="photos/JO2_2875.JPG" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="photos/IMG_1824.JPG" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="photos/JO2_2955.JPG" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="photos/IMG_3913.JPG" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="photos/JO2_2957.JPG" alt="...">
                        </div>

                    </div> <!-- CAROUSEL-INNER -->
```

Comment: For that you should use images as `background-image` not as img src.

Comment: Check out this method https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/6s5u8de1/

Answer (score 4):

There is a better and a very simple way to do this.
Keep all your carousel code within the bootstrap column within a row(Grid system)
And give some class name like **.carousel-column** in my example and then do two things.

1.Set some height and width as per your wish in your custom css file.
2.And set **img-responsive** in your code in the mail HTML Page for carousel items.

It worked for me, hope it will work for all.

```
HTML CODE:
<!-- Carousel to highlight main services-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 carousel-column">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- 1.Carousel Indicators-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" class="active" data-
slideto="0</li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- 2.carousel Items (Picture plus data)-->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/book2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-cus" >
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Web Development</h1>
                        <h3>Let's begin development.It really is about who you are and what you can do</h3>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/book.jpg" class="img-responsive img-cus">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Twitter Bootstrap</h1>
                        <h3>A HTML,CSS,Javascript library for responsive 
mobile first web development</h3>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" 
href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/coffee.jpg" class="img-responsive img-cus" 
>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Java Tutorials</h1>
                        <h3>A powerful secure server side object oriented 
programming language</h3>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" 
href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Now We will create the carousel controls-->
        <a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-
slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>

        <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-
slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now do this in CSS file

```
    CSS Styling:
      .carousel-column{
        height:500px;
        width:900px;
        margin:0 auto;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Check Demo [here](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/pedLop)

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" style="background-image:url(http://dentistry.utah.edu/images/slider-banner/roy-hume.jpg); ">
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="background-image: url(http://dentistry.utah.edu/images/slider-banner/school-dentistry-students.jpg);">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- CAROUSEL-INNER -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel,
.carousel-inner {
  height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  max-height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't have more up votes. This worked like a charm.

Comment: This is genius.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `img src="..."`, then use `class="img-responsive"` and in css `width="100%"`.

Answer (score 1):

it worked like that

```
<div class="carousel-item activo">
  <a href="#" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="01.jpg" alt="Alternate Text" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to change img css that please check

```css
.carousel,
.carousel-inner {
     height: 100vh;
}

.carousel img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="photos/JO2_2978.JPG" alt="xmas_orchestra">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="photos/JO2_2875.JPG" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="photos/IMG_1824.JPG" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="photos/JO2_2955.JPG" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="photos/IMG_3913.JPG" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="photos/JO2_2957.JPG" alt="...">
                        </div>

                    </div> <!-- CAROUSEL-INNER -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 min-width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 max-width: none;
 object-fit:cover;
 object-position:center;
}
```

Please replace you CSS code.